# Where to disclaim multiple third-party copyrights in project?

Tags: copyright, license-notice, attribution

I am building a software that in its theoretical form would use logos from several different financial companies to enhance user experience and identification. I intend to use their websites' favicons and since they are not original material and cannot be included in the software's licence, how would I disclaim these copyrighted images inside the repository?

Bear in mind that we are talking about 20+ potential companies, would it be one or two I would include directly in the `README` of the project pointing to all rights reserved to each company.

What I sense is that:

- I would have a general disclaimer in the `README` stating that logos are copyrighted by their respective owners;
- Point out to another file in the repository where each copyright is thoroughly listed and disclaimed.

But **where** would this file be placed, how should it be **named** and how should it be **structured** in terms of disclaimers?

<sup>**[Obs]**</sup> I don't know the precedent for this in open source software, so should including these images be simply a no-go for the project, feel free to drop in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The more I think about this question, the more I think you have a bigger problem than simply *I have no right to redistribute these logos under a free licence*.  I think the real problem is that you have no right to redistribute them *at all*.

They are, as you point out, copyright images.  I can see nothing inherent in the nature of a favicon that grants you permission to hoover up a bunch of them from random corporate websites and include them in your software.

So I don't think you're allowed to do this *at all*, and thus the question of how to do it in a particular way becomes irrelevant.  Sorry.